# Two articles of Poincaré

Tags: reference-request, relativity-theory

In Jammer's book *Concepts of Simultaneity* on page 108, there is a reference to two of Poincaré's papers:

- "...his 1904 lecture on St. Louis..."
- "...his contribution to the *Lorentz Festschrift*."

Unfortunately there is no bibliography in the book, and an internet search does not reveal anything. How can I find a pdf of these papers?

PS: I am not sure if such bibliography type of questions are welcome here. But given the importance of the persons involved and the historical importance of the topic, I guess it can be tolerated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poincare's [lecture given during the 1904 World's Fair was published in 1906.](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183418771)

The [Lorentz Festschrifft talk is discussed in this paper](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1204/1204.6575.pdf), which has a footnote to the original published version, and a translation:

*Poincaré, Henri, "La théorie de Lorentz et le principe de réaction", Archives
néerlandaises des sciences exactes et naturelles. Recueil de travaux offerts par les
auteurs à H. A. Lorentz (The Hague: Nijhoff) Ser II, 1900, 5, pp. 252-278. See my
discussion of Poincaré and his work on the violation of the principle of reaction in
Lorentz's electron theory: Granek, Galina, "Poincaré’s Contributions to Relativistic
Dynamics", Studies in History and Philosophy of Modern Physics 31, 2000, pp. 15-
48.*

When looking for items like this include more terms: e.g., "Poincare Lorentz Festschrifft".  The paper that is linked above show up first in the list.

Comment: The links are already included ... mouse over the answer!